# Ajax calls and JQuery: stop previuos ajax calls

Tags: ajax, jquery

In a jsp page, when a user clicks a button, an ajax call is triggered.
If the user clicks again and again the button, I would that only the last ajax call be valid and only its response be considered.

I use:

```
  var lastRequest=null;
  $('#button').click(function() {           
  if (lastRequest) {
    lastRequest.abort();
    lastRequest = null;
  }

  lastRequest = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MyAction.do",
            success: function (response) {
                  response= $('<div/>').append(response);  
            }
      });       
  });
```

With Firebug, I see that some request are aborted, but not all.
I think that if an ajax call is triggered, it's not possible to ignore the response, is it?

**EDIT**

If I set a var in MyAction.do and I read it in the success callback, is it possible to have a conflict in the success callback?

In case, how could I prevent that behaviour?

Comment: Your approach is good and should work. You cannot abort requests that received the response. A better approach is to implement a queue system.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with aborting ajax-calls is that it can be pretty random when it works.

A workaround that I've used once or twice is counters:

```
var lastRequest=null;
var started = 0, finished = 0;
$('#button').click(function() {           

  ++started;
  lastRequest = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MyAction.do",
            success: function (response) {
                  //Only do stuff on the last active request
                  if(++finished == started)
                    response= $('<div/>').append(response);  
            }
      });       
});
```

Comment: If I set a var in MyAction.do and I read it in the success callback, is it possible to have a conflict in the success callback?

Answer (score 0):

use  `object.abort()` to discard data that have been called by service
i have add the code as to click on a button to abort service you can try it with respect to your case :)

```
  lastRequest = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MyAction.do",
            success: function (response) {
                  response= $('<div/>').append(response);  
            }
      });       
  });

$(document).click(function() {lastRequest.abort() });
```